# how to make call the api during button active?

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift3

In this i am having three sections in a table view in which first section will have addresses and radio buttons if i click on radio button it will active and the particular address will be posting depending on the address selection the third section needs to call the api and load the data in the second table view which is present in third section can anyone help me how to do this ?

here is the code for table view class

```
  func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int
    {
         if ((addressSelected == true || checkIsPaymentRadioSelect == true) && selected == false) {
            return 3
        }else {
            return 2
        }
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String?
    {
        if ((addressSelected == true || checkIsPaymentRadioSelect == true) && selected == false) {
            if (section == 0) {
                return "SHIPPING ADDRESS"
            }
            else if (section == 2) {
                return "SHIPPING METHOD"
            }
            else  {
                return ""
            }
        }
        else {
                if (section == 0) {
                return "SHIPPING ADDRESS"
                }
                else{
                    return ""
                }
        }
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int{
        if (section == 0)
        {
            return shippingArray.count
        }
        else
        {
            return 1
        }
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat{
        if ((addressSelected == true || checkIsPaymentRadioSelect == true) && selected == false){
            if (indexPath.section == 0){
                return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
            }
            else if (indexPath.section == 1){
                return 62
            }
            else {
                print(height)
                return CGFloat(height)
            }

        }
        else{
            if (indexPath.section == 0){
                return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
            }
            else if (indexPath.section == 1){
                return 62
            }
            else {
                return 0
            }

        }
    }


  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    if (indexPath.section == 0)
    {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! AddressTableViewCell
        tableDetails.isHidden = false
        activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
        let arr = shippingArray[indexPath.row]
        cell.deleteButton.tag = indexPath.row
        cell.nameLabel.text = arr["name"] as? String
        cell.addressLabel.text = arr["address"]as? String
        let mobilenumber : Any =  arr["number"] as AnyObject
        cell.mobileNumberLabel.text = "\(mobilenumber)"
        cell.radioButton.tag = indexPath.row
        cell.editButton.tag = indexPath.row
        cell.deleteButton.tag = indexPath.row
        cell.editButton.isHidden = true
        cell.deleteButton.isHidden = true
        cell.radioButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(selectRadioButton(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
        cell.deleteButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(deleteAction(button:)), for: .touchUpInside)
        let checkIndex = self.checkIsRadioSelect.index(of: indexPath.row)
        if(checkIndex != nil){
            cell.radioButton.isSelected = true
            cell.editButton.isHidden = false
            cell.deleteButton.isHidden = false
        }
        else
        {
            cell.radioButton.isSelected = false
            cell.editButton.isHidden = true
            cell.deleteButton.isHidden = true
        }
        if (checkIsPaymentRadioSelect == true){
        let defaultvalue  = arr["default"] as! Int
        if defaultvalue == 1 {
            cell.radioButton.isSelected = true
            cell.editButton.isHidden = false
            cell.deleteButton.isHidden = false
            addressSelected = true
            tableDetails.tableFooterView?.isHidden = false
        }
        }
        return cell
    }
    else if (indexPath.section == 1){
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "addresscell", for: indexPath) as! CreateNewAddressTableViewCell
        cell.newAddressButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(newAddressAction(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
        return cell
    }
    else {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "shippingmethodcell", for: indexPath) as! MethodTableViewCell
        cell.delegate = self
        cell.boolDelegate = self
        cell.shippingTableView.reloadData()
        if shippingRadio == true {
            cell.select = shippingRadio
            cell.boolSelected()
            cell.shippingmethodURL()
            cell.shippingTableView.reloadData()
        }
        else{
            cell.select = methodRadio
            cell.shippingTableView.reloadData()
        }
        return cell
    }
}
```

in this cell class i had got the api data and is passed to table view as shown in the code now i need to call api during cell selection of address can anyone help me how to implement this or any alternative for this

```
 var chekIndex:IndexPath?
    var arrayss =  [String:Any]()
    var keys = [String]()
    let urlString = "http://www.json-generator.com/api/json/get/bVgbyVQGmq?indent=2"
    var delegate: CheckoutDelegate?
    var heightConstant: Int?
    var name = [String]()
    var totalCount = 0
    var radioSelected:Bool?
    var radioSelection: Bool?
    var boolDelegate: BoolValidationDelegate?
    var select:Bool?

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        radioSelection = false
        self.shippingmethodURL()
        shippingTableView.delegate = self
        shippingTableView.dataSource = self
        shippingTableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
        shippingTableView.estimatedRowHeight = shippingTableView.rowHeight
        // Initialization code
    }
    func paymentRadioAction(button : KGRadioButton) {
        _ = button.center
        let centralPoint = button.superview?.convert(button.center, to:self.shippingTableView)
        let indexPath =  self.shippingTableView.indexPathForRow(at: centralPoint!)
        if button.isSelected {

        } else{
            chekIndex = indexPath
            radioSelection = true
            self.shippingTableView.reloadData()
            self.boolDelegate?.boolvalidation(bool: radioSelection!)
        }
    }
    func shippingmethodURL() {
        guard let url = URL(string: self.urlString) else {return}
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url, completionHandler: {(data, response, error) -> Void in
            if let data = data, let jsonObj = (try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .allowFragments)) as? [String:Any] {
                self.arrayss = jsonObj
                self.keys = Array(jsonObj.keys)
                for value in jsonObj.values {
                    if let array = value as? [[String:Any]] {
                        for element in array {
                            if (element["name"] as? String) != nil {
                                self.totalCount += 1
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.shippingTableView.reloadData()
                    let sectionHeight = self.arrayss.count * 31
                    let cellHeight = self.totalCount * 44
                    self.shippingHeightConstraint.constant = CGFloat(sectionHeight + cellHeight)
                    self.heightConstant = Int(self.shippingHeightConstraint.constant)
                    self.delegate?.heightConstant(int: self.heightConstant!)
                }
            }
        }).resume()
    }
    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return arrayss.count
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
        return self.keys[section]
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        let key = self.keys[section]
        let a :[Any]  = arrayss[key] as! [Any]
        return a.count
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "shippingCell", for: indexPath) as! ShippingMethodTableViewCell
        let key = self.keys[indexPath.section]
        var a :[Any]  = arrayss[key] as! [Any]
        var dictionary = a[indexPath.row] as! [String:Any]
        let name = dictionary["name"]
        let price = dictionary ["price"]
        cell.methodLabel.text = name  as? String
        cell.priceLabel.text = price as? String
        cell.radioButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(paymentRadioAction(button:)), for: .touchUpInside)
        if chekIndex == indexPath {
            cell.radioButton.isSelected = true
        } else {
            cell.radioButton.isSelected = false
        }
    return cell
    }
```

and here is the image for the three sections

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GtM9e.png)  [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T6ysj.png)

Comment: There are no native radio buttons in iOS, so you must be using something you're not telling us about.

Comment: i used kgradio button third party library used for buttons @matt

Comment: Cool, but since this is a question _about_ the radio buttons, don't you think that information could be important to put into the question?

Comment: no but should after making active then it need to show the third section so to understand i mentioned there is this the correct way of implementation ? @matt

Comment: i am asking regarding my api loading in cell class that is third section @matt